# jQuery iterating over objects using %

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see the use of "%" a lot in [this](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/) jQuery documenation.

Example:

```
$( "input" ).each( function( i, el ) {
var elem = $( el );
elem.val( elem.val() + "%" );
});

$( "input" ).val(function( index, value ) {
    return value + "%";
});
```

What is the meaning of, "%" in these contexts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not have any special meaning. The examples merely append a character to a string. It could just as well be this:

```
$( "input" ).val(function( index, value ) {
    return value + "foobar";
});
```